# How to determine if data has finished loading swift using firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a loading screen while retrieving data from firebase firestore. How would I determine if the data has completely loaded so the user isn't staring at a blank page?

Comment: That depends on how you're loading the data. If you show the [minimal code that reproduces where you are currently stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is much more likely that somebody can help you move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did in one of my app. Add this function into your project

```
func startLoadingAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)

    self.opQueue.addOperation {
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Call this function at before you start to fetch the data from firebase. At the end of your call add this.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works beautifully :) I really appreciate it!